# form closing An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: c#, forms

Hi I have a form and i want to open another form when user close the current form as you can see here :

```
private void frmDashboard_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            frmConcerns a = new frmConcerns();
            a.ShowDialog();
        }
```

But when i click on the close button i get this error :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Error creating window handle.
```

Comment: This normally crashes with a StackOverflowException.  Your Close() call causes the FormClosing event to get fired again.  I suspect your real code does it slightly different and you actually managed to create ten thousand dialogs.  After which the OS pulls the plug and won't let you create any more windows.  Don't call Close(), it was already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.Close()` closes the current form - which is actually being done right now already because otherwise the `FormClosing` event wouldn't have been invoked. **Remove that line**.

Also, if you want to show a dialog as a modal window, you should provide the parent form, so instead of calling `a.ShowDialog();` rather call `a.ShowDialog(this);`.

If the error is still there I can assure you that the code you've shown will be correct after the modifications I've suggested - I've done similar things before. In that case the error must occur in other parts of your code you've not shown us.